# Results in browser not appearing after slow response from server using an UpdatePanel in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am having a problem where the browser is not updated after I submit a form with UpdatePanel in C#.

Everything worked fine until I was required to change the SMTP server.  The previous SMTP server returned a result virtually instantaneously, where this "new" server takes 30+ seconds to return a result after the Send() function is called.  After switching to the new server, from the users perspective it does not appear as if anything happened when they submit the form.  From the developers perspective, I can debug and step through the code. Everything completes without error on the server but the results are not visible in the browser.

I am guessing the browser thinks the server timed out and stops waiting for the response, but I am not positive.  Is there a setting that I need to adjust to account for the slow response?

Here are some code snippets to show what I am doing.

I am using an UpdatePanel for a form that has a couple interactive elements (country, state, zip code look ups).  Here is the basic structure:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <!--FORM STUFF HERE -->
       <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitForm" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CssClass="submit" CausesValidation="False" />
       <div runat="server" id="postSubmitMessage" Visible="False">
         <!-- DYNAMIC MESSAGE BASED ON FORM SUBMISSION -->
         <ul id="infoList1" runat="server" Visible="False">
           <!-- LIST OF INFO FOR THE USER -->
         </ul>
         <ul id="infoList2" runat="server" Visible="False">
           <!-- ANOTHER LIST OF INFO FOR THE USER -->
         </ul>
       </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

All of the interactive elements function and the form submits as expected.
The function that executes when the form submits is basically this:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (!Page.IsValid)
        return;
    //SAVE INFO TO DATABASE CODE IS HERE
    postSubmitMessage.Visible = true;
    infoList2.Visible = true;

    //SEND A NOTICE TO THE USER.
    //PROBLEM HAPPENS WITH THIS FUNCTION.
    SendAnEmail();
}

protected bool SendAnEmail()
{
    SmtpClient mailer = new SmtpClient("slow.server.com");
    MailMessage theMessage= new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress(fromEmail, fromName),
                Subject = "Subject String Here",
                Body = "Hi this is the Email. Test",
                IsBodyHtml = false
            };
    mailer.Send(theMessage);  //THIS LINE IS EXTREMELY SLOW
    return true;
}
```

When I comment out the line to send the email, everything works correctly and the browser displays the results.

Any ideas what I could do to guarantee the browser will wait for the response?

Side note:  I realize it's not good to wait this long for a response as the user will likely think something is wrong, start clicking, refreshing, and resubmitting.  I am currently in a development environment in which I am forced to use the slow responding server.  When in production there will be a snappier server, but I need to be able to execute and guarantee things are working during testing before I push to production.

Thanks.

Comment: You can give that panel an id, then call a refresher function from codebehind after sending email? Maybe you can give that button a "auto post-back true" value?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I am not exactly sure what you mean by a refresher function so I tried a couple things.  First I added a call to the "Update()" method of the UpdatePanel after sending the email.  This didn't seem to do anything.  Second, I moved the code that sets the visibility of the result areas to after the call to the email.  Neither got the job done, it still appears as if nothing happened after submit.  AutoPostback does not appear to be available for buttons, or at least it's not in the intellisense options for that tag.

Comment: Maybe linkbutton instead of button?

Comment: The button type does not seem to matter in this case.  It is about the timing and losing the connection between the server and client when the long process is running.